# How to use relative file path for the images in elgg/mod folder?

Tags: elgg

In elgg 1.7.10, I have to use a absolute full path for all the images, how can i use the relative path for plugins in the mod folder?

thanks!

Comment: what kind of images are it that you need to show? Avatars, user uploaded, or images used in the CSS of your site?

Answer (score 2):

Just Use the "/mod/[pluginname]/[graphic_folder]/image.jpg"

Let me know if you were asking some thing else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try
**elgg_get_plugins_path() . 'folderName/pages/add.php';**

Comment: elgg_get_plugins_path() gave me filesystem absolute path `/var/www/html/mod/`